# No tests were found: Class not found: "com.example.myapplication.ExampleInstrumentedTest" on android studio testing

Tags: android, android-studio

I wanted to run an instrumented test as this tutorial: https://developer.android.com/studio/test

I wanted to run a uiautomator test but before that first I tried to run a deafult already existing test file, `MyApplication2\app\src\androidTest\java\com\example\myapplication\ExampleInstrumentedTest.kt`

The file is like this:

```
package com.example.myapplication

import androidx.test.platform.app.InstrumentationRegistry
import androidx.test.ext.junit.runners.AndroidJUnit4

import org.junit.Test
import org.junit.runner.RunWith

import org.junit.Assert.*

/**
 * Instrumented test, which will execute on an Android device.
 *
 * See [testing documentation](http://d.android.com/tools/testing).
 */
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class ExampleInstrumentedTest {
    @Test
    fun useAppContext() {
        // Context of the app under test.
        val appContext = InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().targetContext
        assertEquals("com.example.myapplication", appContext.packageName)
    }
}
```

Then, I tried to run the test file with: right clicking on the flie > Run "ExampleInstrumentedTest"

But I got an error:

```
Process finished with exit code 1
Class not found: "com.example.myapplication.ExampleInstrumentedTest"
```

and not sure you need this info but just in case here is `build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'

//    added
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.uiautomator:uiautomator:2.2.0'

}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aRPwW.png)